# Next book in learning General Topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, soft-question

I have just finished the book "C Adams & R Franzosa - Introduction to Topology. Pure and Applied". My aim is to reach to the level of the book "G E Bredon - Topology and Geometry". Bredon's book is not only too advanced to study after Adams', but also I don't think that it is a readable book at all for a self-learner like me. Please someone tell me a book for general topology more advanced than Adams' book but readable esp. for self-learning .

Thanks a lot.

Some remarks:

1- If you've not see Adams' topology, it is similar to "J Munkres - Topology - 2ndEd" in level and content but more readable for self-learning.

2- **If** more advanced than Munkres' topology is not 'general' topology anymore, i.e. it becomes many branches in topology afterwards, I would like to take that more advanced branch(s) of topology which is/are 'near' to the field of real analysis.

Comment: Bredon's book is not a general topology book, if it wasn't clear. It has a general topology chapter, which I think is intended more as a reference for the reader who occasionally has to check some details. The meat of the book is the algebraic and differential topology in chapters 2 onwards. I don't really think Bredon's book expects more than the general topology that should be covered in any general topology book, though I do think it's probably difficult to appreciate if it's the first place you see manifolds, since he goes rather fast when introducing them.

Comment: @Mike Miller - I chose Bredon's book to study just to find more advance general topology. I am trying to find a book in general topology preferably with inclination to real analysis. Ryszard Engelking, General Topology sound good; is there any book you may know. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ryszard Engelking, General Topology, ISBN 3-88538-006-4, 1989.

Comment: It's seems a very nice book type of what I meant. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This book is a precious one! Best book for lower intermediate level.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any of those books...

Simmons Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis should be readable however.

Introduction to Metric and Topological Spaces by Sutherland is a nice book at a lower level.

Comment: Simmons' book is readable but same level (or even lower) as Munkres'. And, Sutherland's book is even lower level than Simmons'.

Comment: Kelley and Willard are both up a level. Speaking as an analyst I think Simmons is far as you need to go to learn analysis.