# Supportive book(s) for unproven-theorems of General Topology by R Engelking?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am studying General Topology by R Engelking. And, it has **many** theorems left without proofs. Some of them are very hard and I don't think the author had intention to leave them as exercises.

Would someone please tell me how to find the proofs of the unproved theorems? Any book, links, ...?

EDIT - In bounty section I have explained my question in details.

Thank you.

Comment: Change the book?

Comment: @Masacroso - Any suggestion? I got the book from [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333510/next-book-in-learning-general-topology/1333522#1333522) ; if it had proofs for all theorems it is really good for an advanced book but still very readable for self learning. Thank you.

Comment: @AlphaE: what is your background in topology? What other topology books have you read?

Comment: @anakhronizein - Introduction to Topology. Pure and Applied by C Adams & R Franzosa - It's like Topology by Munkres (topic covering and level), but more readable (i.e. for somebody without need to attend at lectures to understand it.)

Comment: I actually find Munkres to be easy to read because he is conversational. Nonetheless, it probably depends on the person. I also wouldn't go as far to say that Adams and Franzosa's textbook covers the same topics as Munkres. They chose to include more applications and a few side topics (e.g. knot theory and even a little game theory) while leaving out emphasis on the metrization theorems, separation axioms, Tychonoff, and several other details. I see in your other question you wish to go on to Bredon. Munkres would do that, but Franzosa would also. Just start reading it and go back if needed.

Comment: @anakhronizein - Thank you because I think now that I can ask my original question more clear: Munkres' book could be a supportive to Franzosa's, because if some theorems were left without proof (as exercise or whatever) in Franzosa's, some of them still could be found in Munkres'. My question is: Is there a General Topology book that is: 1- more advanced than Munkres' (same level as Engelking), 2- it still is 'general' topology not algebraic or ..., 3- has proofs for many of the unproven-theorems of Engelking (as a 'supportive' book to Engelking)? [I copy this comment for a bounty].

Comment: Can you give an example (or examples) of the kind of unproven theorems in Engelking you are talking about?

Comment: @ArthurFischer - Two examples of many: "The Kuratowski theorem yields: 3.7.1. THEOREM. If $X$ is a compact space and $Y$ is a Hausdorff space, then the projection $p:X\times Y \to Y$ is perfect."; it is a kind of conclusion from another theorem but still difficult for me to prove formally and in details as independent theorem. Some of them are that type and some others another type: "Implications $(ii)\implies (iii)$ and $(iii)\implies (iv)$ are obvious" 3.7.16. THEOREM; many "obvious" in the book which I think need detailed proof to be written.

Comment: Yeah, I think those examples are perfect exercises. For 3.7.1 the only real obstacle to show that the map is perfect is showing that it is closed, which the (fully proven) Kuratowski theorem gives you; there is no reason to re-prove this. For 3.7.16 since $\beta Y$ is _a_ compactification of $Y$, if something holds for _all_ compactifications of $Y$, it holds for $\beta Y$. Similarly, if something holds for $\beta Y$, it holds for _some_ compactification of $Y$. If these implications are not obvious, maybe you don't have the "mathematical maturity" to handle Engelking at this point.

Comment: @ArthurFischer - Yes, I agree, I think I don't have the mathematical maturity for Engelking's book and I think that I need a book 'between' Engelking's and Munkres' book which is a lot 'wordy' comparison to Engelking's book. Do you know any book of this type?

Comment: @ArthurFischer - ... or some book as same level as Engelking's book but more 'wordy-er' than Engelking's?

Comment: I don't think you can find any book that gives explanation to every small detail. I am afraid you won't find what you are looking for.

Comment: @AlphaE: I think you will gain more mathematical maturity if you work through the exercises of books like Munkres and Franzosa's. It seems you are rushing through things.